# Laravel issue with post author name display

Tags: laravel

can someone tell me why do I get this error:

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object
```

This is the part of code where I call that property:

```
<!-- Author -->
<p class="lead">
    by
    <a href="#">{{ $post->author->name }}</a>
</p>
```

And here is that relation:
**Post.php**

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

And here is the line from database migration

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
```

Here are parts of code from component and controller from where I call this variable:
**COMPONENT**

```
public function render()
{
    $posts = Post::all()->where('published', '===', 1);
    return view('components.posts-display', [
        'posts' => $posts
    ]);
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    return view('single-post', [
        'post' => $post
    ]);
}
```

**SOLVED**
I have changed the author method name to a user and it worked without any issues. If someone in future sees this feel free to explain it to me, please :)

Comment: What about your controller?

Comment: @BülentAkgül edited my question with this information :)

Comment: @SeadSilajdzic are you sure that you have any author associated with the $post in the database?

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI https://prnt.sc/vc37rj I think it does work because when I click on the number in user_id column it gets me to the user who is its author

Answer (score 0):

Your component is incorrect because you should specify which relations should be added to the collection.

```
public function render()
{
    $posts = Post::where('published', 1)->with("author")->get();
    return view('components.posts-display', [
        'posts' => $posts
    ]);
}
```

Comment: if I do the query this way then I get all posts not just ones where published is true and also this does not work in terms of author name :D

Comment: I edit my answer, and removed '===' since it's wrong. You can use '=' if you want to, but you don't have to. In the posts table, do you have user_id or author_id as foreign key?

Comment: user_id is my foreign key :D

Comment: Still does not work but it worked when I changed that author method name to user ... weird